# Resize Bootstrap 4 Dropdown Caret Size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, caret

Im using Bootstrap v4 framework in my html page. now i would like to resize or increase caret size in my dropdown list. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Here it is my code

```
<div class="container">  
<form name="books">
    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" style="height:3rem">
        <option>Select Category</option>
        <option value="1">Tamil</option>
        <option value="2">English</option>
        <option value="3">Mathematics</option>
        <option value="4">Science</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that just increase the size of the border

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: .3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: "";
    border-top: .5em solid;
    border-right: .5em solid transparent;
    border-left: .5em solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

`-webkit-appearance: none;` to disable default caret and add it as background image.

```css
 select.form-control{
    background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right #fff;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">  
<form name="books">
    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" style="height:3rem">
        <option>Select Category</option>
        <option value="1">Tamil</option>
        <option value="2">English</option>
        <option value="3">Mathematics</option>
        <option value="4">Science</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```